# Calculating weighted average by GroupBy.agg and a named aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, functools

Pandas version 0.25 supports "Named Aggregation" via function `agg` and `namedtuples`. You need to pass column, aggregator pairs as the [doc](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/groupby.html#aggregation) describes. It also says:

> > > If your aggregation functions require additional arguments, partially apply them with functools.partial().

I would like to apply this principle to get a weighted average (besides a simple count and average).
My input table is

```py
import pandas as pd

t = pd.DataFrame({'bucket':['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'], 'weight': [2, 3, 1, 4, 3], 
                  'qty': [100, 500, 200, 800, 700]})
```

and my query fails:

```py
import functools
import numpy as np

t.groupby('bucket').agg(
        NR= ('bucket', 'count'),
        AVG_QTY= ('qty', np.mean),
        W_AVG_QTY= ('qty', functools.partial(np.average, weights='weight'))
   )
```

with an error message:

```py
TypeError: 1D weights expected when shapes of a and weights differ.
```

I assume the problem comes from fixing the parameter to be another column instead of a constant? How can I make this work without the workaround that uses `apply` and a lambda expression that returns a `Series`?

Comment: IIUC, you need to pass `group['weight']` into `np.average`, not the string.

Comment: How exactly? Can you provide the exact syntax?

Comment: The issue is that `GroupBy.agg` acts on a single column, however a weighted average requires 2 separate columns; one for the values, another for the weights. In that case `GroupBy.apply` is required as you can pass a DataFrame.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A weighted average requires 2 separate Series (i.e. a DataFrame). Because of this `GroupBy.apply` is the correct aggregation method to use. Use `pd.concat` to join the results.

```
pd.concat([t.groupby('bucket').agg(NR = ('bucket', 'count'),
                                   AVG_QTY = ('qty', np.mean)),
           (t.groupby('bucket').apply(lambda gp: np.average(gp.qty, weights=gp.weight))
             .rename('W_AVG_QTY'))], 
          axis=1)

#        NR     AVG_QTY  W_AVG_QTY
#bucket                           
#a        2  300.000000      340.0
#b        3  566.666667      687.5
```

---

This **can** be done with `agg`, assuming your DataFrame has a unique Index, though I can't guarantee it will be very performant given all the slicing. We create our own function that accepts the Series of values and the entire DataFrame. The function then subsets the `DataFrame` using the Series to obtain the weights for each group.

```
def my_w_avg(s, df, wcol):
    return np.average(s, weights=df.loc[s.index, wcol])

t.groupby('bucket').agg(
        NR= ('bucket', 'count'),
        AVG_QTY= ('qty', np.mean),
        W_AVG_QTY= ('qty', functools.partial(my_w_avg, df=t, wcol='weight'))
   )

#        NR     AVG_QTY  W_AVG_QTY
#bucket                           
#a        2  300.000000      340.0
#b        3  566.666667      687.5
```

Comment: Thank you! I agree, this solution well demonstrates that you **can** use `functools.partial` with GroupBy.agg to calculate a weighted average and it also demonstrates that you **should not** do it this way ;)